# JNativeHook_6363198016012433909.dll: Access is denied

Tags: java, dll

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Kelvz1\AppData\Local\Temp\JNativeHook_6363198016012433909.dll: Access is denied
```

I have these error how can I fix it.
Some of the users can access these and no problem, but some user cant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a strange random error that sometimes manifests on Windows 7 and Windows 8. Everything is fine one day and then suddenly you get an access denied exception when Java tries to access a DLL in the temp folder.

I've found deleting the TEMP folder and letting it re-create it automatically usually solves the problem.

If you are the author of the code that put the DLL in the TEMP folder then I would recommend you change the code to put the DLL in a folder under this path instead as I have yet to see this problem there: %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\

I read somewhere this can be caused by Microsoft Security Essentials but it doesn't look like this is installed on the computer that just experienced this problem.

I've seen this happen with many different DLL files, like jna.dll.

If you're using JNA and it has this problem you can change the temp directory system property and JNA will create the file in a different directory. This code should work for this.

```
    String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
    if (osName.toLowerCase().startsWith("windows")) {
        // we change the temp directory because sometimes Windows is stupid and doesn't want to load jna.dll from the temp directory
        File tempDir = new File(System.getenv("USERPROFILE") + "\\AppData\\Local\\MyCompany\\temp");
        System.out.println("Using temp dir: " + tempDir.getPath());
        tempDir.mkdirs();
        System.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir", tempDir.getPath());
    }
```